# How to hide a script on mobile

Tags: html, mobile

I just launched a mobile version of my site and I’m having a hard time hiding a live chat script on the mobile `hide-for-small`. This is the code I don't want displayed on the mobile version:

```
<script src="http://www.smartreachdigitalchat.com/scripts/invitation.ashx?company=?????"></script>
```

All the things I don’t want displayed on the mobile I simply write:

```
<div class="small hide-for-small"><script src="http://www.smartreachdigitalchat.com/scripts/invitation.ashx?company=?????"></script></div>
```

…and it would hide from mobile devices and only display on desktop computers, but here it’s not working; it seems to be hiding from both desktop and mobile.

What can I do to make the script execute only on desktop computers?

Comment: How have you implemented the .small and .hide-for-small CSS classes?

Comment: have you tried something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/3540295/2603230 to detect if user is mobile and then load/don't load javascript

Comment: Hi Luke, No, we haven't implemented the .small and hide-for-small css. Thought it would be a simple hide code

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
<script>
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    //Do something for mobile
    alert("MOBILE");
}else{
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://www.smartreachdigitalchat.com/scripts/invitation/apexchat.js?company=2051";
    document.write(script.outerHTML);
}
</script>
```

It will show live chat on computer and hide on mobile device:

[image: show on computer]

[image: hide on mobile device]

Comment: No, but it added the livechat to the very bottom right of the screen and made the screen wider. Had to scrool down. thought it was gone till i scrolled down

Comment: you mean when you visit on mobile, the script is still loaded? Have you removed/commented `<div class="small hide-for-small"><script src="http://www.smartreachdigitalchat.com/scripts/invitation.ashx?company=?????"></script></div>`?

Comment: yes on the mobile. I did remove my the <div class="small hide-for-small"><script  should I have?

Comment: @booya1969 what mobile device you are using?

Comment: here's what my code looks like if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    //Do something for mobile
}else{
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://www.smartreachdigitalchat.com/scripts/invitation.ashx?company=????";
    document.write(script.outerHTML);

<div class="text-center hide-for-small">
<script src="http://www.smartreachdigitalchat.com/scripts/invitation.ashx?company=????"></script>
</div>

Comment: @booya1969 you should remove `<div class="text-center hide-for-small"> <script src="smartreachdigitalchat.com/scripts/…; </div>`

Comment: I did, tried with and without the <div class="text-center hide-for-small"> <script src="smartreachdigitalchat.com/scripts/…; </div> and same results. I really appreciate you trying

Comment: can you give me a company name for test? @booya1969

Comment: @booya1969 it's working fine for me. Can you edit your full code now in your question?

Comment: I think I answered my question by accident on here. If you view the page, you'll see the code written on the front of the page on the bottom

Comment: you forget to add `<script>` tag? It's some Javascript

Comment: I added it just now, and i get a message usinging mobile then i click ok and the livechat is still there. can you test

Comment: yes i've test and the js didn't load... are you sure only `http://www.smartreachdigitalchat.com/scripts/invitation.ashx?company=?????` is loading live chat?

Comment: could be tracking as well. The client is using a geo fencing marketing company who supplied the livechat code

Comment: i cannot test that js cause it return `window.ApexChatResponse = "Invalid company specified."`

Comment: <script src="http://www.smartreachdigitalchat.com/scripts/invitation.ashx?company=2051"></script>

Comment: it is working really really fine for me. Try the updated answer. and what exactly android device you are using? Do "mobile" alerted?

Comment: see my screenshot in answer, it really doesn't show on mobile device

Comment: Yea, strange. I just tried it on a iphone and ipad and the live chat is showing up.

Comment: @booya1969 send your whole HTML page to eflyjason@gmail.com ok? thanks!

Comment: ah... you write one more `<script src="http://www.smartreachdigitalchat.com/scripts/invitation.ashx?company=2051"></script>` on page... Remove that code should be ok.. I've reply you with the correct the code......

Comment: @booya1969 You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)